# How to validate a child checkbox is checked while parent checkbox is checked using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to validate atleat one child checkbox is checked while parent checkbox is checked in a array of

checkbox using jquery.

```
<form name="frm" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return validation()"> 
    <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" id="cat1" value="C1" />
    <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sub_cat[]" id="cat1_s1" value="S1" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sub_cat[]" id="cat1_s2" value="S3" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sub_cat[]" id="cat1_s3" value="S4" /></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" id="cat2" value="C2" />
    <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sub_cat[]" id="cat2_s4" value="S4" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sub_cat[]" id="cat2_s5" value="S5" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="sub_cat[]" id="cat2_s6" value="S6" /></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If i am check id="cat1" checkbox i need to alert please select atleast one child from the list. How to validate using jquery parallely it apply for parent checkbox id="cat2".

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: a JSFiddle could be usefull

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$("[name^=cat]").change(function() {
    var childBox = $(this).parent("li").find("ul li input:checked");
    if (!childBox.length)
        alert("Please select a child checkbox");
});
```

Comment: supposing OP has used ul li as he descirbed in question .. personally i might have done with startswith .. but in the context of the question this is perfect

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name^='cat']").change(function()({

if($(this).is(":checked"))
{

if($(this).find(":checkbox:checked").length)
{
// if checked do your stuff
}else{
 alert("please select child element");
}
}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
$("#cat1").click(function() {
    // this function will get executed every time the #cat1 element is clicked (or tab-spacebar changed)
    if($(this).is(":checked")) // "this" refers to the element that fired the event
    {
        $("#panel :input").attr("checked",true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class to the parent checkboxes and use the following code to verify the child selection.

EG. Here parent checkbox has class named "parent"

```
   $('input.parent').change(function(){       
    var id = $(this).attr('id');       
    if($('input[id^="'+id+'_"]:checked').length < 1){
        alert("Please select at least one child.");
    }
});
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BtLF/)

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing this:

```
$(function () {
    // ^= attribute which starts with
    $("input[name^='cat']").on("change", function () {
        // If it's been checked and the number of checked children
        // is smaller then one
        if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).next().find("input[name^='sub_cat']:checked").length < 1) 
            alert("Please select something");
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tQtXV/

Answer (score 0):

My own suggestion would be:

```
$('input[name="cat[]"]').change(function(){
    $(this).next('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$('input[name="sub_cat[]"]').change(function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest('ul');
    parent.prev().prop('checked', function(){
        return parent.find('input[name="sub_cat[]"]').length === parent.find('input[name="sub_cat[]"]:checked').length;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3ueTk/1/).

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).